# Cannot build GEGL in windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image-processing, gimp, gegl

what is the command for ./configure to buil gegl. i need gtk+ and babl and i have that.i have also installed msys/mingw. but which argument i should give to run ./configure in msys?

do i need to save all the libraries (gegl, gtk, babl) in C:\msys\1.0?

Comment: Have a look at this link:
http://wiki.gimp.org/index.php/Users:Beginner_Developer%27s_FAQ#How_to_compile_Gimp_for_Windows.3F

Comment: thanks. but i dont really need the GIMP. i need to use GEGL and babl libraries for image processing in visual studio 2010. then i will use it as a native code for android. i have seen this link: http://lightningismyname.blogspot.com/p/compiling-gimp.html#comment-form and followed all the steps for windows. now i want to know how i can compile a code in visual studio. what changes i need to make in the properties of the project. i just want to compile a simple program using gegl functions.